# NPY file viewer

Tags: windows, python

I'm looking for a NPY (NumPy .npy format) file viewer for Windows 7. The Spyder that comes with [Anaconda](http://continuum.io/downloads) is quite OK but tends to be pretty slow when viewing arrays.

[image]

Comment: so you want something that mimics what spyder can do, or something that displays npy file like the image in the OP?

Comment: @depperm  displays npy file like the image in the OP