# Viewer for Python pickle files

Tags: windows-7, python

I'm looking for a [pickle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pickle_(Python)) (standard mechanism for object serialization in Python) file viewer for Windows 7. I'm aware that it's unlikely that a general viewer exists (i.e. that could open any pickle), but I missed interested in simple pickles containing lists or dictionaries. I know I can open it using Python, but I would prefer to have some GUI like Matlab for .mat files, or [Spyder for NPY files](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/23305/903):

[image]

Comment: Ah, I shall write one right now :)

Comment: Have you considered converting pickle data to XML (ex. http://www.picklingtools.com/html/xmldoc.html ) and then using an XML viewer? This may be an easier path to achieve what you want.

Comment: There is a GUI software for Pickle files. It's called PickleViewer
It's in Devolopment and in coming updates it will have a visualizer for the pickle file. [To the GitHub repo](https://github.com/Matix-Media/PickleViewer)

Answer (score 3):

Why not use an [iPython](http://ipython.org/)/[Jupyter](https://jupyter.org/) notebook, you can:

- Load **any** pickle file,
- Interactively see what the data type(s) are,
- Display slices of any arrays, dictionaries, etc.,
- Plot graphs of any numeric data with pyplot,
- Manipulate the data before display,
- Save & Export the results, etc.

Comment: That's not point and click. I sympathize with the question, because I make a lot of pkl files and usually forget what's in them and I don't want to do a lot of typing to unpack them, I'd rather just have point and click, like an XML editor.

Answer (score 2):

On Github, there is a tool called PickleViewer. With this tool you can simply

- Edit
- Load
- Save

Pickle files.
It's free. In the program is a text editor, with which you can easily edit the files.
There is also a treeview to view the structure of the file.

[To the Repo](https://github.com/Matix-Media/PickleViewer)

[Download version 0.7.5](https://github.com/Matix-Media/PickleViewer/raw/master/versions/0.7.5/PickleViewer075_setup.exe)

[To the latest release](https://github.com/Matix-Media/PickleViewer/releases)

[image: PickleViewer 0.7.2 Screenshot]

[image: PickleViewer Logo]

Answer (score 2):

For this exact reason I decided to build a website to view files directly in your browser without uploading any of that info online:

- https://github.com/ch-hristov/Pickle-viewer
- https://fire-6dcaa-273213.web.app/

Comment: Does that website do anything except asking for a file name? Nothing happens here

Comment: @ThomasWeller hi, Thomas, doesn't work for all .pickle files. Basically, all files produced >= python 3.4 may cause failure to open, working on those atm. You can use python 3.3 or earlier with it for now., Feel free to contribute https://github.com/ch-hristov/Pickle-viewer